# How to filter all the paths from the urls using "sed" or "grep"

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I was trying to filter all the files from the URLs and get only paths.

```bash
echo -e "http://sub.domain.tld/secured/database_connect.php\nhttp://sub.domain.tld/section/files/image.jpg\nhttp://sub.domain.tld/.git/audio-files/top-secret/audio.mp3" | grep -Ei "(http|https)://[^/\"]+" | sort -u

http://sub.domain.tld
```

But I want the result like this

```bash
http://sub.domain.tld/secured/
http://sub.domain.tld/section/files/
http://sub.domain.tld/.git/audio-files/top-secret/
```

Is there any way to do it with `sed` or `grep`

Answer (score 1):

### with grep

If your grep has the `-o` option:

```
... | grep -Eio 'https?://.*/'
```

If there could be multiple URLs per line:

```
... | grep -Eio 'https?://[^[:space:]]+/'
```

### with sed

If the input is always precisely one URL per line and nothing else, you can just delete the filename part:

```
... | sed 's/[^/]*$//'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep`

```
$ echo ... | grep -o '.*/'
http://sub.domain.tld/secured/
http://sub.domain.tld/section/files/
http://sub.domain.tld/.git/audio-files/top-secret/
```

Comment: OP didn’t mention what OS he's using so you should specify that it only works with GNU `grep`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `match` function of `awk`, will work in any version of `awk`. Simple explanation would be, passing `echo` command's output to `awk` program. Using `match` matching everything till last occurrence of `/` and then printing the sub-string to print just before `/`(with -1 to `RLENGTH`).

```
your_echo_command | awk 'match($0,/.*\//){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH-1)}'
```

Answer (score 1):

GNU Awk

```
$ echo ... | awk 'match($0,/.*\//,a){print a[0]}'
$ echo ... | awk '{print gensub(/(.*\/).*/,"\\1",1)}'
$ echo ... | awk 'sub(/[^/]*$/,"")'

http://sub.domain.tld/secured/
http://sub.domain.tld/section/files/
http://sub.domain.tld/.git/audio-files/top-secret/
```

xargs

```
$ echo ... | xargs -i sh -c 'echo $(dirname "{}")/'

http://sub.domain.tld/secured/
http://sub.domain.tld/section/files/
http://sub.domain.tld/.git/audio-files/top-secret/
```